# How to write a simple pine-script that plots portfolio balance

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to run a simple script that would just allow me to back test from/to a certain date for a stock. Just to keep it simple, lets say the startdate = Jan, 1, 2010 and I have $100,000 to invest into AAPL.

forloop(stardate, +10 min incremenets,

{ 
   if (5 day sma == some condition)
       buy as many AAPL stocks as balance allows

if (stockprice == some condition)
       sell all stocks
   }
then plot portfolio balance if buy/sell happened.

If anyone can help me out or at least point me in the right direction I would greatly appreacite

Answer (score 0):

I think Pine Script [Strategies](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Strategies.html) is what you need.
They plot the portfolio balance (equity curve) automatically.

[image: Screenshot]
*Screenshot taken from [RSI Divergence Indicator strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/script/qSLcZSyw-RSI-Divergence-Indicator-strategy/)*

Detailed information about Strategies can be found on [Kodify](https://kodify.net/tradingview-programming-articles/#trading-strategies)
Or if you're a visual learner, there are several YouTube videos on strategies and backtesting, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxDSFdvAei4&list=PLM0BBafRCnRNhvMxyiqScZWV_h41raut6&index=10).

Answer (score 0):

You can use strategy.equity. At least that's what it's called in v5.

```
plot(strategy.equity, title="Equity", color=#ffffff)
```